# Git not pushing all subfolders or subdirectories

Tags: git, github, command-line-interface

I am making a Django Project usign Python 3.5

I have completed my project and I am pushing it to [Github](https://github.com/vaibhavchhabra800/Major-Project) but the src folder which contains all my main code is just not pushed what should I do ?

All that I did is went to my Major Project Directory and typed them-->

```
git init
git add .
git remote add origin git@github.com:vaibhavchhabra800/Major-Project.git
git commit -m "message about the commit"
git push origin master
```

Now my main files which contain my apps setting.py ,manage.py ,etc have not been pushed but rest of the folders have been pushed ,only the src folder has not been pushed what should Ido?

Comment: Are any of these subdirectories empty?

Comment: Try `ls -a src`. Does this show a `.git` directory in the `src` directory?

Comment: are there any error messages?

Comment: When I do git add . and git status , I get this On branch master
nothing to commit, working tree clean

Comment: `git push` pushes *commits*, not individual files. Either the commit(s) you push contain the files, or they don't; there's nothing in between. If your commit has the file in question, it has gone there along with the commit. If not, it has not.

Comment: Did you try the commands in my second comment? What was the output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to commit the code first to the repository:

```
git commit -m "message about the commit"
```

and then you can do the first time

```
git push origin master
```

after the first `git push origin master` you just can do

```
git add .
git commit -m "message"
git push
```

And check your'e `.gitignore` file, if there are any folders/files to be ignored

Comment: Sorry I forgot to put it in the code, I had done it but still i get the same issue , I tried to do this 3 times ,not working also updated my code in question

Comment: do you have a .gitignore file?

Comment: No there is no file gitignore

Answer (score 0):

I also got the same problem in my project. In my case, I accidentally initialized my git inside my client folder instead of the main project folder, resulting in this weird thing where I would only somewhat push the client folder. I solved it by removing all the git folders using `rm -rf .git` and then reinitializing and recommitting my work. Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

Yesterday, i got problem like that.
You should try :

```
$ git pull origin master
```

Then you can do :

```
$ git push origin master
```

I wish it can help you....

Answer (score -2):

for python language just add `__init__` file in your subfolders